# using backbone .save method trying to extract json data in a php file

Tags: php, ajax, backbone.js

I'm using backbone in my application and I'm attempting to update a json file using the backbone method .save method 
here is the site http://dalydd.com/projects/backbone/backbone.html

here is my js this is working fine

```
 var ModalInfo = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
  person:'',
  occupation:'',
  home:'',
},
url:'sample.php',
});

 var developer = new ModalInfo();
developer.toJSON();
 developer.save({person:'madan', occupation:'developer', home:'middtown'}, {
wait:true,
success:function(model, response) {
console.log('Successfully saved!' + model + response);
},
 error: function(model, error) {
console.log(model.toJSON());
console.log('error.responseText' +model);
}
});
```

Here is the php in my sample.php I'm trying to get the contents of json.js decode it append it with my new data and then decode it and return it as the response

```
 <?php

 $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('json.js'), true);
 for ($i = 0, $len = count($json_data); $i < $len; ++$i) {
      //do the right logic
 }
 file_put_contents('json.js', json_encode($json_data));
 $final_data = file_get_contents('json.js', json_encode($json_data));
 echo $final_data;
 echo(var_dump($_POST));
 ?>
```

when i try to echo out the super global post I get array(0)

I'm hoping someone could help me out with my php and why I can't extract any post data in sample.php when i use the .save method in backbone - when i echo out server request method it states post i just want to grab the post data and write it to the file and then return it am I going about this the wrong way - any help is appreciated - I have been racking my brain on this.  My first step is just figuring out why i can't get any post data even though firebug is telling me it's posting when I load the page - you can check also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in that fact that unless you are posting form-encoded data, the `$_POST` superglobal does not get populated by PHP.  You need to get at the raw posted input.  You can do that like this:

```
$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

You can actually use any of the various PHP file input methods here (i.e `fopen`/`fread`, `file` (useless in this context), etc.) . However the above will probably be the easiest if you are not going to be dealing with large chunks of JSON input to the point where memory management becomes more of a concern.

Comment: Hey Mike this was a huge help. What is the meaning of php://input I don't think I've ever used it before but it worked also had another quick question.  Currently in my php file i am posting the data from backbone as json decoding it then I"m essentially getting json from json.js and decoding that also then using array_merge to merge both of them and then encoding that and using file_put_contents to update the json.js file! Is there an easier way to do this? there must be

Comment: @JamesDaly `php://input` is just PHP's input stream wrapper.  See this link for further information on wrappers available in PHP:  http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php. Your use case around actually reading and writing from an actual javascript file and using this in addition to some sort of an AJAX method seems odd.  I guess you are trying to persist some application data in JSON format?  Why not read the contents of json.js in javascript, then change it however it is to be changed in the application and then save the entire structure via `save()` call?

Comment: @JamesDaly My apologies in that I only have limited exposure to Backbone (I tend to do more server to backend work) so I am not that familiar with how `save` would typically be used.